# Sum $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left(\sqrt[n]{\vphantom{\large A}3\,}\, - 1\right)^{\alpha}\quad\mbox{where}\quad \alpha \in {\mathbb R}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left(\sqrt[n]{\vphantom{\large A}3\,}\, - 1\right)^{\alpha}
\quad\mbox{where}\quad \alpha \in {\mathbb R}
$$

Does the sum converge for some values of $\alpha$ ?.

I have proved, that
$\displaystyle{%
\lim_{n \to \infty}n\left(\sqrt[n]{a\,}\, - 1\right)=\ln\left(a\right)}$, but I'm not sure if that will be usefull for this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is useful. *Very* useful. You know that there are two constants $c,d > 0$ such that for all large enough $n$

$$\frac{c}{n} \leqslant \sqrt[n]{3} - 1 \leqslant \frac{d}{n}.$$

That allows you to say precisely for which $\alpha$ the series converges, and for which it diverges.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it...
For $\alpha > 1$ it would diverge and in other cases converge?

Comment: For which $\alpha$ does $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\alpha}$$ converge?

Comment: For $\alpha > 1$ it converges.

Comment: Right, and we have (assuming $\alpha > 0$, the inequalities are reversed for $\alpha < 0$) $$\frac{c^\alpha}{n^\alpha} \leqslant (\sqrt[n]{3}-1)^\alpha \leqslant \frac{d^\alpha}{n^\alpha}.$$

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$(\sqrt[n]{3}-1)^\alpha= \left(e^{\frac{1}{n}\log3}-1\right)^\alpha\sim_\infty \frac{\log^\alpha3}{n^\alpha}$$
so the series is convergent if and only if $\alpha>1$ by asymptotic comparison with the Riemann series.

Answer (score 2):

We have that that $\sqrt[n] 3>1$. Thus let $d_n>0:\sqrt[n] 3=1+d_n$. Then $3=(1+d_n)^n\geq \frac {n(n-1)}{2}\cdot d_n^2$ from Newton's Binomial. This means that $0<d_n<\sqrt {\frac {6}{n(n-1)}}\iff 0<\sqrt[n] 3-1<\sqrt {\frac {6}{n(n-1)}}=> 0<(\sqrt[n] 3-1)^a<(\sqrt {\frac {6}{n(n-1)}})^a$. This will help you determine the $a$.